# Unresolved reference for Firestore reference in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pass on the text selection of the user as a string to convert it to the document path of my Firestore collection.

Unfortunately, I get the error message:

> Variable 'enteredText' must be initialized in line

```
val docRef = db.collection("storage").document(enteredText)
```

and the "(enteredText)" is underlined in red.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
package com.example.servus

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

import android.view.View
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val autotextView
            = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.autoTextViewStart)
    val autotextViewZiel
            = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.autoTextViewZiel)


    // Get the array of languages
    val languages
            = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Languages)
    // Create adapter and add in AutoCompleteTextView
    val adapter
            = ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, languages)
    autotextView.setAdapter(adapter)
    autotextViewZiel.setAdapter(adapter)

    var enteredText: String


    val button
            = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn); if (button != null)
    {
        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            enteredText =
                autotextView.getText().toString() 
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, enteredText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }


    // getString(R.string.submitted_lang)

    val db = Firebase.firestore

    val value1= findViewById(R.id.value1) as TextView
    val value2= findViewById(R.id.value2) as TextView
    val value3= findViewById(R.id.value3) as TextView


    val docRef = db.collection("storage").document(enteredText)

    docRef.get()
       .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
           if (document !=null) {
                Log.d("exist", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")

               value1.text = document.getString("value1")
               value2.text = document.getString("value2")
               value3.text = document.getString("value3")
           } else {
               Log.d("noexist", "No such docoument")
           }
       }
       .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("notexisting", "Error getting documents.", exception)
       }
}
```

}

Comment: I cannot see in your code this line `db.collection("strecken").document(enteredText)`. Can you add it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. The code was correct, the mistake was in my question. I changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the "enteredText" variable underlined in red because you didn't initialize it. You can either declare it as a member of the class:

```
private lateinit var enteredText: String
```

Using the `lateinit` keyword, meaning that you'll have to provide a value later in your code, or you can assign a value once you declare it:

```
var enteredText: String = ""
```

**Edit:**

```
val button
        = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn); if (button != null)
{
    button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        enteredText =
            autotextView.getText().toString() 
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, enteredText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    val db = Firebase.firestore

    val value1= findViewById(R.id.value1) as TextView
    val value2= findViewById(R.id.value2) as TextView
    val value3= findViewById(R.id.value3) as TextView

    val docRef = db.collection("storage").document(enteredText)
    docRef.get()
       .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
           if (document !=null) {
                Log.d("exist", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")

               value1.text = document.getString("value1")
               value2.text = document.getString("value2")
               value3.text = document.getString("value3")
           } else {
               Log.d("noexist", "No such document")
           }
       }
       .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("notexisting", "Error getting documents.", exception)
       }
    })
```

Comment: When I use the 2nd method the error in the code dissapears, but when my Main Activity launches the app crashes. Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.servus/com.example.servus.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but storage has 1

Comment: When I use the 1st method, it wants me to delete the "private" because "Modifier 'private' is not applicable to 'local variable'". After I delete that and launch the app it also crashes when opening my MainActivity. Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property enteredText has not been initialized

Comment: To solve the issue, move the code related to Firestore inside the click listener, as in my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works! I still get some small erros "Fail to get file list com.example.servus", "getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array", "Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000" but everything runs as it should. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the second issue, there can be a lot of reasons why get that. So I recommend you post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.